# My CEO is trying to change my position

Tags: position

> **Question**: Should i change my position or should find some other company?

**Explanation:**
I am a full-stack dot net developer working in a startup software company in India. we had 5 employees. Two dotnet developers, two PHP developers, and one designer. Things went fine until my company started focusing on PHP and Wordpress.

When they started giving more importance to PHP and WordPress one of our team who is a 5 year experienced professional in dotnet left the company. I am the junior dot net developer with 1.7 years of experience and I rarely get a project. I got one big project for UAE company and been working on it for a month which is 95 % completed and unfortunately, because of the lockdown the client company is in shutdown and we have to wait till the lockdown is over to deliver the project.

My problem is this that since the company has started focusing much on PHP and WordPress because of the time constraint I guess, I get less or no projects to work and I have asked them so many times but they instead are trying to change my job from developer to **functional consultant or sometimes the CEO talks about making me a business analyst** at such an early age while there is already a 10 year experienced PHP professional working in my company.

My company loves me but I feel like they don't understand that being a developer is not just cool but my passion for a very long time. I don't find a perfect reason to jump to another position. I feel like I am being thrown away and finally landed here so that I could get some advice from well-wishers.

*NOTE:* I have some pending backlogs from my college and have to complete them so that I will get my degree. So because of this drawback, I consider the job I am currently working as a golden opportunity but at the same time, I think that my company is trying to dominate me because of my situation hence they can make me a slave working in that same company till end. In India, it is very difficult to get a job with no degree in hand.

---

**Update 28 Jan, 2024:**
I resigned from the above company 3 years ago. Worked for 3 years in another company. I learned a lot in my career and life. I grew stronger personally and career wise. I cleared my backlogs, got my degree. I joined a new company again on October 2023. Honestly, I should say, this company is a gift God gave me after going through all those hard times. Good position. Good environment. Good salary. Flexibility. Positive people and culture. I am happy today. Thank you God. Guys, if you are struggling, do not lose hope. Keep going. Do good. Be patient. Your good times will come.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have edited my question. I hope now it is clear. I don't care about the downvotes. I need some good advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't make the decision for you.

But I can tell you this. The CEO is probably looking out for you. If they are moving from .net to PHP, then the number of projects you can contribute to is dropping. The CEO has to either let you go, or find some way to make you a productive member of the company.

The question for you is can you be a productive member until you can finish your degree?

The CEO, ignoring any existing contracts or labor laws, has a few options:

- Pay you the same salary to do less and less each month;
- Cut your salary but keep you in the same position;
- Change your position which might also include a change in salary;
- Let you go.

Sometimes management likes an employee and tries to find a way to keep them.

Comment: What would you do if u were in my situation?

Comment: See the first line of the answer. We can't decide for you.

Comment: Hi @mhoran_psprep. While casually browsing my past activities, I found this question. Felt like updating it. Check out my latest update on the question. Thank you.